# launchfile remote machines: Temporary failures

Tags: roslaunch, ssh, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community!

**Setup:**

- Ubuntu 16 with ROS-kinetic, LAN, static ip
- Raspberry Pi 2 with ROS-kinetic, LAN, static ip

Each one is with the beginner_tutorials ready to rock... It works if i start roscore and talker/listener node on the corresponding machine. As minimum lanuchfile, i tried to start the beginners_tutorial/talker on my Pi from PC with:

```
<launch>
      <machine name="TCG" address="TCG" user="user" env-loader="/home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/env.sh"/>
      <node machine="TCG" pkg="beginner_tutorials" name="talker" type="talker"/>
</launch>
```

**Result:**

```
......
remote[TCG4-1008-0]: ssh connection created
SUMMARY
========
PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: kinetic
* /rosversion: 1.12.14

MACHINES
* TCG

NODES
/talkerTCG4 (beginner_tutorials/talker)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13173]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311
setting /run_id to 89e119632c594e
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13186]
started core service [/rosout]
error launching on [TCG-0, uri http://TCG:42313/]: Temporary failure in name resolution
Launch of the following nodes most likely failed: beginner_tutorials/talker
^C[TCG] killing on exit
remote[TCG-0]: unable to contact [TCG] to shutdown remote processes!
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I followed [Network Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup), and every thing works, pinging, ssh, ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_IP, and so on.

**Question**
From
Temporary failure in name resolution
there is a problem with the names, have i mixed-up some name (etc/hosts, hostname, launch-file parameter)

I am grateful for every advice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315666/launchfile-remote-machines:-temporary-failures/) by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2019-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just ran into the same problem, and I solved this problem according to this [ros wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup#Configuring_.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-hosts)

and configure the  `/etc/hosts` file as follows

IPAddress              Hostname
192.168.1.10        localhost

Note that hostname/ip may vary according to your devices, and the ros wiki suggests to set Alias, while my /etc/hosts file has no Alias column, so I just skip them.

---

Originally posted by [tfe](https://answers.ros.org/users/49929/tfe/) with karma: 26 on 2019-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1